# Code to write to save an input data on my web page to a server

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am a beginner in web design and i created a simple web application to just collect some information and i want it to send the inputted data to a server to store it for me. I really need a simple code to input within my code to send it to the server and save it.

```
<style>
        #Home { background-color:whitesmoke;}
        #Site_Details { background-color:snow;}
        #Dredger_Details { background-color:ghostwhite;}
        img { width:800px;
              height:500px
        }
    </style>
    <style type="text/css">
        td, th { border: 1px solid #CCC; }
        table {border: 1px solid black; }
    </style>
    <SCRIPT language=Javascript>
        <!--
        function isNumberKey(evt) {
        var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
        if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
        return false;

        return true;
        }
        //-->
    </SCRIPT>




<!-- Start of first page: #Home -->
    <div data-role="page" id="Home">

        <div data-role="header" data-theme="a">
            <h1><strong><font size="5">WELCOME</font></strong></h1>
        </div>
        <!-- /header -->

        <p><font size="30"><strong>Welcome.</strong></font></p>

        <img src="img/Image31.jpg" /><br />

        <p><a href="#Site_Details" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-icon-bars ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-b">Please click here to continue.</a></p>

        <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-theme="a">
            <h1><strong><font size="5">WELCOME</font></strong></h1>
        </div>
        <!-- /footer -->

    </div>
    <!-- /page one -->

    <!-- Start of Second page: #Site_Details -->
    <div data-role="page" id="Site_Details">

    <div data-role="header" data-theme="a">
        <h1><strong><font size="3">SITE AND DREDGER'S NAME AND TARGET.</font></strong></h1>
    </div>
    <!-- /header -->

    <div style="color:blue">
    <p><font size="5">Please fill in the following details.</font></p>
    </div>

    <form>
        <label for="textinput-s"><font size="6"><strong>Site:</strong></font></label>
        <input name="textinput-s" id="textinput-s" placeholder="SIte..." value="" data-clear-btn="true" type="text" data-theme="d" /><br />
    </form>

    <form>
        <label for="textinput-s"><font size="6"><strong>Dredger Name:</strong></font></label>
        <input name="textinput-s" id="text1" placeholder="Dreder Name..." value="" data-clear-btn="true" type="text" data-theme="d" /><br />
    </form>

    <form>
        <label for="textinput-s"><font size="6"><strong>Daily Dredger Target:</strong></font></label>
        <input name="textinput-s" id="text2" placeholder="Dreder Target..." value="" data-clear-btn="true" type="text" data-theme="d" /><br />
    </form>

    <form>
        <input data-role="none" value="Save" type="submit">
        <input data-role="none" value="Reset" type="submit">
    </form>

        <p><a href="#Dredger_Details" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline">Please click here to continue.</a></p>

    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-theme="a">
        <h1><strong><font size="3">SITE AND DREDGER'S NAME AND TARGET.</font></strong></h1>
    </div>
    <!-- /footer -->

    </div>
    <!-- /page two -->

    <!-- Start of Third page: #Dredger_Details -->
    <div data-role="page" id="Dredger_Details">

        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="a">
        <h1><strong><font size="5">DREDGER ACTIVITY.</font></strong></h1>
    </div>
    <!-- /header -->

    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <font color="blue" size="5"><strong>Date:</strong></font>
            </th>
            <th colspan="8">
                <label for="date"></label>
                <input type="date" name="date" id="date1" value=""  />
            </th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <form>
                    <h4>Start Time:</h4>
                </form>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form>
                    <label for="time"></label>
                    <input type="time" name="time" id="time" value="" />
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <form>
                    <h4>End Time:</h4>
                </form>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form>
                    <label for="time"></label>
                    <input type="time" name="time" id="time1" value="" />
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr >
            <td>
                <strong>Effective Dredging(Mins):</strong>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="txtChar" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" type="number" name="txtChar" placeholder="Effective Dredging(Mins)..." />
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <strong>Other Activities/Downtime(Mins):</strong>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form>
                    <input id="Number1" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" type="number" name="txtChar" placeholder="Other Activities/Downtime(Mins)..." />
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <strong>Main Eng(Hrs):</strong>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form>
                    <input id="Number2" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" type="number" name="txtChar" placeholder="Main Eng(Hrs)..." />
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <strong>Aux Eng(Hrs):</strong>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form>
                    <input id="Number3" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" type="number" name="txtChar" placeholder="Aux Eng(Hrs)..." />
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <strong>Main Eng  Av. Diesel Usage (Ltrs/h):</strong>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form>
                    <input id="Number4" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" type="number" name="txtChar" placeholder="Main Eng  Av. Diesel Usage (Ltrs/h)..." />
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <strong>Comments:</strong>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div data-role="fieldcontain" style="padding:10px; margin:10px; ">
                    <textarea cols="500" rows="100" name="textarea" placeholder="Comments..." id="textarea5" style="height:300px;"></textarea>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <form>
        <input data-role="none" value="Save" type="submit">
        <input data-role="none" value="Reset" type="submit">
        <a href="#Home" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-btn-b">Cancle</a>
    </form>

    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-theme="a">
        <h1><strong><font size="5">DREDGER ACTIVITY.</font></strong></h1>
    </div>
    <!-- /footer -->

        </div>
    <!-- /page three -->
```

Comment: which framework are you using? asp,jsp or something else?

Comment: simple to post the form data add "ACTION" to form tag

Answer (score 0):

For that, you first need some code written in PHP , java or any other language running on your web server to process and save the form data.

every input field you put inside the  tag will be send to the server when you submit the form. modify the action parameter of form to point to the code you have to handle data at server.

```
     <form method = "post" action = "URL">
        <input type="text" name="">
        .
        .
        <input data-role="none" value="Save" type="submit">
        <input data-role="none" value="Reset" type="submit">
        <a href="#Home" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-btn-b">Cancle</a>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

As a beginner in web development you could have a good look at this free video tutorial about web forms.

http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/courses/web-form-design-and-development

After having gone through that you should know exactly what to do and will be well equipped for any form related questions in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment:

Many things are not as they are supposed to.. The form tag should be around all the inputs providing data. It collects its information from its children (inputs) and sends it to a url. In your example, even with adding an action, you'll only get 1 or 2 inputs sent to your server. As mulla.azzi mentioned, you need to provide an action attribute as well. I don't know whether the script tags above are working, but language="Javascript"? never heard of it ... It can go on for quite a while..

While I strongly encourage following web design, and I see you've already tested and tried a bit, there really is a lot out of place in your code snippet. I strongly suggest you follow some tutorials / courses. Not only about HTML / CSS / JS, because that's the easy part. Everyone can write that. But also about the basic principles of stateless applications, server - client interaction. And you will also need to learn how you can recieve the data and do something with it..

Sadly, while there is a very low treshold to start building web pages (html, css), there's still a lot to learn untill you can actually build a functioning website.